CSV import error with pandas. IDE: Spyder
ImportError: C extension: pandas.compat._constants not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext' to build the C extensions first.
I infer that compiled code could be executed globally, I am using anaconda3 distribution.
I was expecting to build the c extensions by python running setup.py build_ext.
There is no setup.py in the pandas site package.
__init__.py  _libs       _version.py        arrays       core    plotting        tests
__pycache__  _testing    _version_meson.py  compat       errors  pyproject.toml  tseries
_config      _typing.py  api                conftest.py  io      testing.py      util


You haven't given us very much information to go off here (where you got the files you've listed, why you need to compile the library instead of install with pip, etc.), but try visiting the actual Pandas GitHub page

@AustinDuling Thank you for you response. I reinstalled pandas with pip and got it to work. The files you see are from site-package for pandas. Likely came with anaconda install.

If your problem is solved, try closing the question.

Are you sure I can do that?
